# How to check if text appears on page in rails functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing

I am currently writing functional tests for my controller, and I want to check if a line

This is a test line

appears on my page.

I tried using

```
assert_select "p" do
  assert_select "this is the test line"
end
```

but i think something is wrong with this line.

What is the best way to do this in rails version 3?

Comment: Please do not keep updating the code in your question -- it makes the Q&A format fall apart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're just looking for:

```
assert_select "p", "this is the test line"
```

See [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html) for more info about `assert_select`.

Note that the line above depends on the text being wrapped in a `<p>` tag, and being a literal match.  If it's in another tag, you'll need to specify the correct selector.  If you'd like to match on a Regex, that is also supported, via:

```
assert_select "p", /test line/
```

Note that this will not be very performant, as it will scan through *all* `<p>`'s in your document.  Consider a more tightly specified selector, like a class or ID on the element you're targeting.

Comment: I think my problem is that this p is inside a bunch of divs, for example <div><div><div><p> this is a test line</p></div></div></div>.
Does this mean i have to specify that in the tag? Like div.div.div.p?

Comment: So i found the answer, i added a class to the p and in assert_select did p.class and then "string"
worked like a charm.

Answer (score 15):

Without specifying a tag:

```
assert_match "this is the test line", response.body
```

Answer (score 0):

this works with rails 6:

```rb
assert_selector "p", text: "this is the test line"
```

doc: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers

(I was getting `Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery`)